# Problem creating url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url

I want to create a url as below 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false

I used the following code to create this

```
NSURL *jsonURL;
NSString *strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false"];
jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strurl];
[strurl release];

NSLog(@"json Url%@",jsonURL);

NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
if(jsonData == nil){
//NSLog(@"Data NIL .....");
}
else{
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    dic = [json objectWithString:jsonData error:&error]; 
    [json release];
}
```

But every time I get `jsonURL` to be nil .

I think the problem is due to "|".  Has someone come across same issue? If yes, can you help me out?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the | characters with the appropriate code?

Comment: Remove the `|` and see if it works. Then you will *know* whether it's the `|`.

Comment: @nope i dont know about that if you can help it would be great .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 
`[NSURL URLWithString:[strurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

Comment: While this looks like a great solution, sadly this api sucks and you shouldn't use it. (Doesn't escape everything that must be escaped) There is a CoreFoundation version that does more escaping however.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `URLWithString` says:

> The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. **Must conform to RFC 2396.**

... [which e.g. mentions](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> Other characters are excluded because
>   gateways and other transport    agents
>   are known to sometimes modify such
>   characters, or they are    used as
>   delimiters.
>
> ```
> unwise = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
> ```
>
> Data corresponding to excluded
>   characters must be escaped in order to
>   be properly represented within a URI.

Thus escape them properly as *slf* suggested.

Also, just use a string constant for predefined strings:

```
NSString *strurl = @"http://....";
```

Answer (score 2):

As for your URL issue, Georg is right:

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize%3Atrue%7CBarossa+Valley,SA%7CClare,SA%7CConnawarra,SA%7CMcLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false"];
```

Fixed that issue for me.

However, the next bit:

```
NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
```

Is deeply troubling. You should never do synchronous data reads on the main thread. initWithContentsOfURL is going to spawn a synchronous NSURLConnection to go fetch that data and might return sometime before sunday, but you never know. (This method is ok for filesystem loads, where things are much more deterministic)

Look into an asynchronous loading API like `NSURLConnection` from Apple, or better yet `ASIHTTPRequest`, about which there is ample documentation online.

Happy webservicing!

Answer (score 1):

I think, the root of cause is your string creating method.

```
NSString *strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false"];
```

Try with ...

```
NSString *strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false"];
```

Comment: or simply `NSString* strurl = @"...";`

Comment: Tried this, and it doesn't fix mrugen's issue. Perfectly valid to have a format with no replacements. Investigating now…